# How to implement smart searching of contacts by name and number by T9 in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, t9

I am working on a contacts app and I was wondering if it's possible to search contacts like T9 dealers do (letters associated with each number also filters results). So if I press 2 key, it should search for number '2' as well as 'ABC'.

Code I am trying :

```
let enteredChar = dialerTextField.text!

        var pattern = keysDictionary?[enteredChar.last]

        pattern = "[\(String(describing: pattern!.first)) - \(String(describing: pattern!.last))]"
        // pattern = "[m-o]" Regex
        do {

            let matches = items.filter({

                (item : String) -> Bool in

                let stringMatch = item.range(of: pattern!, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil)

                return stringMatch != nil ? true : false

            })

            let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: pattern!)

            let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey]

            var contacts = [CNContact]()
            var message: String!

            let contactsStore = CNContactStore()

            do {
                contacts = try contactsStore.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

                if contacts.count == 0 {
                    message = "No contacts were found matching the given name."
                }
            }
            catch {
                message = "Unable to fetch contacts."
            }


            print("matches : ", contacts)
        }
        catch {

        }
```

using above code I can search for contact name if I change `pattern` to say "Rob" but it does not work with Regex `"[p-s]"`. I'd like to search with regex. How can this be done? Thank you.

Comment: Do it yourself, it's not that hard. In fact, I give a related question during interviews.

Comment: I am trying too :)

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: I don't know how to do this T9 way

Comment: Should it be a custom keyboard or representing them as buttons is fair?

Comment: I'm representing them as buttons

Comment: Would it be enough to show how the buttons should be implemented? searching the contacts is another story...

Comment: No. I have already done all UI part. I need contact search T9 algorithm.

Comment: Then I would suggest to make the question more clear :) you should mention exactly what's the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no library avaialble that matches exactly what you need.

So

Go to your project and create a new `Custom Keyboard Extension` for your application.

[image]

This was somewhat matching to your T9 keyboard [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNCVmkv_vdI) From youtube

This youtube totorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gczzfq6DuHo) may help you further

### **Algorithm to use**

Create a dictionary which maps each letter to digits

Like `{"a":1,"b":1,"c":1,"d":2,.. "z":9}`

And fetch all contacts and find out the pattern of numbers corresponding to contact names (use the above dictionary for that).

like `{"anna":"2662","baby":"2229","denis":"33647","emila":"36452"}`

Whenever the user starts typing on the keyboard, fetch all patters matching in the above dictionary
Like if user types `"2"` Corresponding matches will be `"anna" and "baby"`.

Eliminate the matches when getting more inputs from user.

Comment: This isn't something I am looking for, thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've already implemented it using Regex :)

Comment: what problem you're facing now

Comment: I am sure this is one of the ways to do it but I did it differently using Regex but I'll accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

to create a rudimentary T9 implementation is quite simple, all you need to do is parse the contacts into a dictionary. the key will be a number and the value will be a list of contacts.

for example if you had a list of contacts: **John, Stan, Dad, Fae** you'd parse it into a dictionary:

```
5666 - ["John"]
7826 - ["Stan"]
323 - ["Dad", "Fae"]
```

as a user types in numbers you'd simply query the dictionary and either display no results or the matching array of contacts.

Comment: Yeah I have an idea of this but I am trying to find a way to make this type of dictionary. This is where I need help with the algorithm